# Cash based Income UK standard visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, money

I'm going to be applying for a UK standard visitor visa in the next few months to visit my daughter in the UK. Although my visa is going to be completely sponsored by my daughter, I'm told I need to show my bank statements.

I own a clothes shop in India and 90% of my daily sales transaction are cash-based, although I deposit that money in a business bank account and pay my invoices and other business bills from that account. I also transfer some money to my personal savings account once a month (also shown in income tax returns as profit) and pay for my day-to-day expenses from it.

1. Does having a cash-based income diminish the credibility of the application?
2. Is there anything I can do to prove my income is legitimate and available to me?
3. Is 3 months statements enough or do I need 6 months minimum?

Comment: You might find [this question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) useful.

Comment: Thanks, David and Henrik for your comments, I've gone through them and I understand the importance of a bank statement in showing the financial situation. My question is more regarding the cash-based income that I receive and deposit in my proprietorship current account. As is there anything I can add to show a clear picture to ECO and make my case strong as my daughter is thinking to apply for a priority visa, I want to make this case as simple and strong as possible for ECO. Again appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes cash based income unfortunately have diminished credibility. 2. Not really, it is what it is, add tax returns if possible 3. Six is better than 3